# Is my tactile push button switch connected properly to reset my STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, switches, reset

[image][image]

[image]

Is my tactile push button switch connected properly to GND so that the NRST pin of my STM32 gets GND and resets the STM32 when pressing the push button?

Please check if my schematic for the push button is correct. For a Nucleo board, the schematic for the push button is different.

I also added the Nucleo board schematic with the push button, which is correct. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome! I tried to clear up your question but I had to guess on a few things what you meant. Please check and re-edit if needed.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly your reset button is any different to the Nucleo schematics? We also don't know where the reset wire goes and what else is there so we cannot say if the reset is correctly made or not.

Comment: @Justme the NRST goes off to the SWD header. So assuming they are copying this to make their own, I don't see why OP thinks theres any difference

Comment: @MCG There is an NRST wire in OPs schematic as well, and we don't know if that is where it differs from the Nucleo.

Comment: @MrGerber yes, I saw that which is why I made an assumption. Was hoping OP would come and either confirm or correct the assumption but doesn't seem to have done that

Comment: the nrst wires goes to pin header with swclk swdio and 3v3 for SWD and I need physical reset to I need to check whether symbol of push is correct on nucleo schematic or else my schematic of push button is wrong inshort I need reset the circuitry (stm32l432 is my schematic ) (144 pin mcu is nucleo )